# Spring Data Mongo: Checking a field of a document and return true/false

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

**Problem:**

I want to make a Mongo Query to find a document by its id and check if a field has a certain value. If yes return true, if not return false. Everything should be done inside Mongo. I dont want to retrieve the document and check in-memory.

**Question:**

1) Is that possible by just extending the ReactiveCrudRepository (I am using Spring 5 Webflux) and having a method annotated with @Query

```
@Query(...)
Mono<Boolean> theMethod(String id, String valueToCheck)
```

2) Or do I have to write a custom Query with ReactiveMongoOperations/Template?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an easy solution with the ReactiveMongoOperations/Template exists function.

```
Mono<Boolean> operations.exists(Query, EntityClass)
```

Depending on your query (search criteria) this function will return true or false.